# Mobile and Tablet responsive in Elementor but not on the actual site?

Tags: plugins, mobile

After editing my website and making it tablet/mobile responsive through Elementor, everything seems to look just right. However, this is only true when I view the website in Elementor. When I try to visit my site by clicking 'Visit Site' then 'Customize', then viewing my website in its tablet/mobile version, the changes I made in Elementor do not seem to reflect. What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: That's an odd way of testing. What happens when you view the pages on a phone or tablet?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the theme which may have 769px breakpoint while for Elementor it is 768px. You can switch your theme to Hello https://wordpress.org/themes/hello-elementor/ which is official Elementor theme. If this works well then you can change the breakpoint of Elementor to match with your theme. You can give this a try - https://elementorresources.com/tutorials/how-to-change-the-tablet-and-mobile-breakpoints-in-elementor/